# What is the name for non-time series data?

Tags: dataset

This feels like it might be a stupid question with a quick answer, but is there a specific term for a dataset that is not classed as time series data?

I do not mean descriptions of the variables e.g. discrete, continuous etc., I mean for a dataset as a whole; for example, what kind of dataset is the classic iris dataset, which does not contain a time dimension?

Comment: I think the closest one is Tabular data, which is any dataset that is presented as a table, but it can hold date dimension anywhere

Comment: Thanks for the input @YaroslawHomenko -- I tend to think of tabular data more as a description of its shape than its contents, i.e. SQL rather than NoSQL 'style' data. It's not a huge problem I have here, I am just finding myself writing "non-time series data" a lot and was wondering if there was a more terse way of saying it :-)

Comment: time independent data seems better than non-time series data to me.